# How to embed all FXML nested controllers in one time?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm programming a JavaFX app and I need to retrieve all controllers (buttons, text fields and a color picker) from my view.

So I created a controller class in order to load all controllers:

```
public class GeneralController extends BorderPane implements Initializable {

    @FXML private Button btnNew;
    @FXML private Button btnOpen;
    @FXML private Button btnSave;
    @FXML private Button btnShare;
    @FXML private Button btnHelp;
    @FXML private Button btnAbout;

    @FXML private ColorPicker clrSelectColor; 
    @FXML private Button btnPencil;
    @FXML private Button btnArrow;
    @FXML private Button btnCircle;
    @FXML private Button btnLine;
    @FXML private Button btnTriangle;
    @FXML private Button btnRectangle;
    @FXML private TextField nbcThickness;
    @FXML private Button btnConfirmThickness;

    @FXML private Button btnCropImg;
    @FXML private Button btnRotateImg;
    @FXML private Button btnInverseImg;

    @FXML private Canvas paintCanvas;
    private GraphicsContext gc;

    public GeneralController() {
        FXMLLoader fl = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/Window.fxml"));
         fl.setController(this);
         try {
             fl.load();            
         } catch (IOException exception) {
             throw new RuntimeException(exception);
         }

    }
```

Problem is: after the load of FXML file, all my controller references are null (certainly due to the fact that controllers are in nested panes).

The FXML file tree is here:

[image: file tree]

(Entire FXML file: https://pastedb.io/paste/283be582-8624-4e13-71f8-838d6cbe15a7#fd3bdf271781a16f773b539ca30478f92ef7c8a9b228e7d630ee48c7eaf72a5f)

How can I load all my controllers (except panes) without having to go through each nested container? (Each controller have a unique ID on all the application).

Comment: show please also your FXML file

Comment: you miss also  fl.setRoot(this);

Comment: I tried fl.setRoot(this) but I've got the rror "Root value is already specified"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that self-loaded FXML is configured differently.

so you must add this line before set controller:

```
fl.setRoot(this);
```

And made changes in FXML:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <top />
  <center />
(...)
</fx:root>
```